# How can I sort my mongoose response by the amount of documents (on another collection) that has a reference to the object of the response?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am programming a back-end in node.js with mongoose to communicate with my mongo database.

At the moment I have two collections: threads and comments.
Comments contain a field named thread which contains the objectID of a document of the threads collection.

Now I would like to sort all threads in descending order on the amount of comments.

So now I have:

```
Thread.find({})
        .then((threads) => {

            function mycomparator(a, b) {
                Comment.find({ thread: a._id }).countDocuments()
                .then((amountOfCommentsOnA) => {
                     Comment.find({ thread: b._id }).countDocuments()
                     .then((amountOfCommentsOnB) => {
                         return amountOfCommentsOnB - amountOfCommentsOnA;
                     })
                })
            };

            threads.sort(mycomparator);

            res.send(threads);
        })
```

But the sorting is not working. When I console.log the amountOfCommentsOnA and amountOfCommentsOnB the result is right. But as I said, the sorting is not.

What do I need to make this working?

Comment: This is not a proper answer but currently what you are doing can be improved. If I were you I would keep a comment counter in `Thread` collection. So, when a new comment is created I would increase the counter from `Thread` collection. Finally, I would do this to get expected result: `Thread.find({}).sort('commentCount')`.

Comment: Yeh that is a solution. But wasnt there a convention or something that it is not nice to save a value in the database that can be calculated? @Dijkstra